# Use the result of multiple select dropdown in case statement

Tags: sql, string, vue.js

I have a vue multi-select component and I need when the user selects an item to get the data from SQL. The user can select up to 4 items. I am struggling to figure out how to do it.

I tried this code in sql and it works if I select two apps but I need to do a condition when I select more or less and I am stuck

```
Declare @item  nvarchar(max)='App1,App2';
SET @sqlApp = Replace(@item  , ',', '.');
------------------- select using parse function------------
select   
user,
count(case when app = PARSENAME(@item  ,1) then 1 end) as app1,
count(case when app  = PARSENAME(@item  ,2) then 1 end) as app2
from AppTable
group by user
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Please show the different scenarios you mentioned to make it more clear and their expected output.

Comment: Is this an sql or Vue issue? You mention both but the problem has to lie within only one of these I presume... Also it's unclear what goes wrong exactly.

Comment: it is a SQL issue , my problem is if the user selects only App1 , I get the count and also I get zero for App2 since both counts are in the select. I need to achieve this: if only app1 selected show app1 count , else if app1 and app2 are selected show count of app1 and app2 .